# Get ampersand modifier to inherit all properties from parent

Tags: sass, bem

I'm using SASS's handy ampersand notation to add BEM-style modifiers to my classes:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: magenta;

    &--selected {
        background: cyan;
    }
}
```

I'm exploring the possibility of only having to apply a single class to my elements (ex: `<div class="box--selected">...</div>` as opposed to `<div class="box box--selected">...</div>`).  I'd like to avoid using `@extend`, it casts too wide a net.  Currently I'm using mixins, which are good, but a little verbose to use for every single class with a modifier.

**What I'd really like to do is get `&--selected` to inherit *all* the properties from the parent enclosure, and *only* from the parent enclosure** - ie ignore any other class definitions of `.box` that careless devs may have inserted.

Comment: It's not good idea to allow modifiers to extend all properties. Your output css file will be bigger and bigger more modifies you have. And what if element should have several modifiers?

Comment: @3rdthemagical makes perfect sense.  BEM actually recommends that you use both the base and modifier classes anyway - this was more of a thought experiment/feature quandary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've expressed the desire to avoid `@extend` but this method may allow you to avoid other dev's definitions of `.box` while still achieving your goal.

You could use placeholders to create your own parent enclosure and extend the placeholder([example of placeholder extension)](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/#article-header-id-6) inheriting only from the placeholder. As a placeholder there is no chance of conflicts with classes from other devs on `.box`:

```css
%box{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: magenta;
}
.box--selected{
    @extend %box;
    background: cyan;
}
```

Compared to mixins this method lacks the use of parameters like the following example from the article mentioned above [[1](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/#article-header-id-6)]:

```css
@mixin padMasterJ ($param: 10px) {
  padding: $param;
}
```

Another thing worth noting is that when `@extend` is used on a parent selection the result will include all nested selectors `@extend` **cannot** be used to directly extend a nested selector.

Comment: Interesting.  Does this differ at all from making a mixin?

Comment: Good question. I've added a bit more info regarding how `@extend` differs functionally from `@mixin`. Hope that is is useful.